# How to call a javascript through wicket framework ?

Tags: javascript, wicket-1.5

Hi I am new to wicket framework, I need to create a context menu so that when I right my context menu should be displayed instead of browser menu. The following is the Javascript code of my context menu in Dojo:

`<script src='dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config='async: false, parseOnLoad: true'></script>`

Now my question is how to call this same javascript through wicket. As I am getting error when I am trying to right the code in my java file to call this javascript

```
private static final CompressedResourceReference DOJO_JS    = new CompressedResourceReference(HomePage.class,"./dojo/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: false, parseOnLoad: true");
```

Comment: 1. Use double quotes for attribute values. 2. Don't override the right-click. 3. What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your " so java can tell what's part of your String and what's not...
Additionally you need to add and remove "s where needed.
The CompressedResourceReference-Constructor expects one Scope and one String. So that's what you have to provide...

```
private static final CompressedResourceReference DOJO_JS    = new CompressedResourceReference(HomePage.class,"./dojo/dojo/dojo.js data-dojo-config=\"async: false, parseOnLoad: true\"");
```